# Looking for node revision author token

Tags: 7, tokens

According to http://drupal.org/node/252241 a revision author token may be available. However I do not see anything referencing revision:author (variation?) in my list of available tokens. Is there something like this?

Comment: Drupal 6 or 7 ?

Comment: Its for Drupal 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For D7, in order to gain access to revision:author tokens, *you have to install* [Revisioning](https://drupal.org/project/revisioning) *module*. (of course you also need token module)

Then you can see *all the available tokens* by going to Help -> Token (/admin/help/token)

So after enabling the module, a new token category, named "Revisions", is available. You can see for example 
**[revision:revision-author]** which refers to "The author (or editor) of the revision" and a bunch of others regarding the revision author.

P.S. As per [this](https://drupal.org/node/1992980) there seems to be currently a bug regarding [revision:revision-author:mail]

Good luck and let me know if you need more help!

Answer (score 0):

This one is for D6 but probably give you a hint: http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/revisioning/revisioning_tokens.inc/6.4

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Custom Tokens](https://drupal.org/project/token_custom) module ?

> It gives the user the ability to create custom tokens for specific
>   replacements that can improve other modules relying on the Drupal 7
>   token API or, for Drupal 6, the Token module.
>
> Versions 7.x-1.x and previours relied on PHP evaluation to build
>   custom tokens.

The idea is to define your own tokens and use them. Also it works with PHP Filter Module.

Install module goto `admin/structure/token-custom/add` to add a new token. Since you want to get the author from node submission select *Token type node*

Answer (score 0):

When I use tokens together with Rules action "After updating existing content" this token gives me the author of the *updated* node (i.e. the author of the latest revision): **[site:current-user]**. (To get an author of the first revision, you can use **[node:author]**.)